# How to get further information about the origin of an exit code?

Tags: shell-script, exit, error-handling, exit-status

Sometimes I need to maintain programs that invoke shell scripts which invokes other programs and scripts. Therefore, when the main shell script ends with exit code 126, it is a struggle to find out which of the invoked scripts and commands set that exit code.

Is there a way to see which command was the reason for the exit code to make it easier to check for its permissions?

Answer (score 7):

If on Linux, you could run the command under `strace -fe process` to know which process did an `exit_group(126)` and what command it (or any of its parent if it didn't execute anything itself) executed last before doing that:

```
$ strace -fe process sh -c 'env sh -c /; exit'
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "env sh -c /; exit"], [/* 53 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f24713b1700) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f24713b19d0) = 26325
strace: Process 26325 attached
[pid 26324] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 26325] execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "sh", "-c", "/"], [/* 53 vars */]) = 0
[pid 26325] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fbdb4e2c700) = 0
[pid 26325] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/"], [/* 53 vars */]) = 0
[pid 26325] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fef90b3b700) = 0
[pid 26325] clone(strace: Process 26326 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fef90b3b9d0) = 26326
[pid 26325] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 26326] execve("/", ["/"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
sh: 1: /: Permission denied
[pid 26326] exit_group(126)             = ?
[pid 26326] +++ exited with 126 +++
[pid 26325] <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 126}], 0, NULL) = 26326
[pid 26325] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=26326, si_uid=10031, si_status=126, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 26325] exit_group(126)             = ?
[pid 26325] +++ exited with 126 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 126}], 0, NULL) = 26325
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=26325, si_uid=10031, si_status=126, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
exit_group(126)                         = ?
+++ exited with 126 +++
```

Above, that was process 26326 that first exited with 126, that was because it attempted to execute `/`. It was a child of process 26325 that last executed `sh -c /`.

If those scripts are `bash` scripts or if they are `sh` scripts and `sh` happens to be `bash` on your system, you could do:

```
$ env SHELLOPTS=xtrace \
      BASH_XTRACEFD=7 7>&2 \
      PS4='[$?][$BASHPID|${BASH_SOURCE:-$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING}|$LINENO]+ ' \ 
    sh -c 'env sh -c /; exit'
[0][30625|env sh -c /; exit|0]+ env sh -c /
[0][30626|/|0]+ /
sh: /: Is a directory
[126][30625|env sh -c /; exit|0]+ exit
```

That doesn't tell us exactly what process exited with 126 but could give you enough clue.

We use `BASH_TRACEFD=7 7>&2` so that the traces are output on the *original* stderr, even when stderr is redirected within the scripts. Otherwise those trace messages could affect the behaviour of the scripts if they do things like `(....) 2>&1 | ...`. That assumes those scripts don't explicitly use or close fd 7 themselves (that's would be unlikely, a lot more unlikely than them redirecting stderr).

Comment: You can use `BASH_XTRACEFD=` to make trace output to go to standard error.

Comment: @cuonglm, the xtrace goes on stderr by default, the point here is to make sure that is not affected by stderr redirections. See edit.

Answer (score 5):

If you set the option `set -x`, then you see the commands that execute in the shell in a trace.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can preload a bit of C code as a shim to trap the call to `exit(126)` and have it issue a `SIGSTOP` signal to the process group, which will pause the process (and its parents in the same group).

For example, if we trap exit code 2 in our shim then run `ls` on a non-existant file:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/meuh/shim_exit.so bash -c ' sh -c "ls -l xxx; echo"; echo '
```

it will background itself with the message

```
[1]+  Stopped  ...
```

and you can see the processes in status `T` wait:

```
~ $ ps f
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
30528 pts/3    T      0:00  \_ bash -c sh -c "ls -l xxx;echo";echo
30529 pts/3    T      0:00  |   \_ sh -c ls -l xxx;echo
30530 pts/3    T      0:00  |       \_ ls -l xxx
```

At this stage you could attach to the processes if they are debuggable, or simply foreground or SIGCONT the processes to continue.

Here's the shim_exit.c code, see the C comment for compiling.

```
/*
 * capture calls to a routine and replace with your code
 * http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308694/119298
 * gcc -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o shim_exit.so shim_exit.c
 * LD_PRELOAD=/home/meuh/shim_exit.so ./test
 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed to get RTLD_NEXT defined in dlfcn.h */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
/* doesnt work for syscall exit_group() */
void exit(int status){
    static void (*real_exit)(int status) = NULL;

    if (!real_exit) {
        real_exit = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "exit");
        char *error = dlerror();
        if (error != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
            _exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (status==126/* || status==2*/)kill(0,SIGSTOP);
    real_exit(status);
}
```

Comment: Clever, though probably doesn't work for commands that call `_exit()` instead of `exit()`.(you'd want to wrap that one as well).